# Stinky Synaptics Trackpad driver - Replacement?

Tags: laptop, drivers, touchpad

Is there a good replacement for my trackpad driver? I have the latest Synaptics one and its crap. It has its helper processes set to Above Normal which cause a lockup when doing video or a game. I have an Asus G50vt.

I would like to maintain the scroll area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/13429/get-side-scroll-area-back-on-laptop-trackpad) which might have an answer you could be interested in:

> Try downloading the latest touchpad drivers (manufacturer specific) from the [Toshiba website](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/home.jsp?nav=Download), otherwise try directly from the [Synaptics site](http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers).
>
> Disclaimer on Synaptics website:
>
> > The Synaptics device driver is
> >     customized to meet the specific
> >     requirements of your device
> >     manufacturer. To ensure that you get
> >     the appropriate device driver for your
> >     system, download your Synaptics device
> >     driver from your system manufacturer's
> >     support website

Comment: The Synaptics driver site has the same one I have.

Answer (score 2):

You should always stick to your manufacture-specific synaptics driver. As shown in [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/13429/get-side-scroll-area-back-on-laptop-trackpad/13457#13457). Synaptics states that:

> *The Synaptics device driver is customized to meet the specific requirements of your device manufacturer. To ensure that you get the appropriate device driver for your system, download your Synaptics device driver from your system manufacturer's support website*

So your best bet is to get [ASUS-specific drivers](http://support.asus.de/download/download.aspx). This ensures the expected functionality, and stability needed for that exact notebook configuration.

Comment: that's just standard legal boilerplate BS. I always install the latest and greatest drivers, because the manufacturer "blessed" ones are always way behind the times.

Comment: I tend to do the same, but in some cases, manufacturers take "shortcuts" or add/remove features so that drivers are more compatible or stable with their hardware. ergo my answer

Comment: The Asus drivers are over a year old.

Comment: The "customized" Synaptics driver that came with my ThinkPad has rather broken scrolling; replacing it with the generic Synaptics driver made it much better.

Answer (score 2):

OP, i agree that one should always be cautious when choosing from where to obtain updates, but, at least in my personal experience, many computer manufacturers abandon putting recent driver updates for older models. heck, my HP site is still trying to get me to put windows vista back on my computer and i'm on 7 (yay).

but to your question: http://www.uscrybe.com/download.php
if your particular synaptics pad is version 6.2 or above, this driver will give you multi=finger gestures and two finger scroll (you guys know you have mac envy ;P) AND will let you draw letters on your mouse pad to perform user defined tasks (among many other cool things).

i bet you can't get THAT on your computer manufacturer's website =)

Answer (score 0):

i usually just go with the default one that windows installs. it doesn't have all the fancy bells*whistles but i find it more reliable. You can try a rollback on the driver?

Comment: Its the one that came with the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have small hands and the tap-2-click was killing me, as I am always typing commands on the servers I support remotely.  I heard the same answer from Asus and Synaptic, "stick with the manufacturer's driver"

If the driver is impacting the functionality of something so essential as typing or simply utilizing the laptop, then there is a problem.

Here's the fix-  If available, download the Elan version of the driver from the manufacturer.  Many, like Asus, utilize two different manufacturer's touchpads that are essentially the same, so the other driver may have the feature options the first driver did not.

For me, I went to Asus support site, downloaded the Elan version after many other's failed, (such as Vista drivers in compatibility mode, etc..) and I was very satisfied with the Elan drivers for my U46e Asus laptop that allowed me to control the touchpad tap-2-click, scrolling, etc.