# Get side scroll area back on laptop trackpad

Tags: windows-vista, touchpad

A week ago I stupidly decided to download the Synaptics driver from their website and install it on my laptop, hoping it would give me more features. It didn't. Instead, it actually removed a lot of the 'features' and capabilities the trackpad had previously.

How can I revert to the older driver or add the side scroll area back to my trackpad? Is it possible to add a two-finger scroll?

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop with Windows Vista.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Synaptics has this functionality as default, given that you have the correct drivers. See if you can find the following setting

> Control Panel > Mouse > Device
>   Settings >
>   Synaptics TouchPad V... > Settings

Inside these settings, you can chose to enable the virtual scroll settings:

> Virtual Scrolling > Enable vertical
>   scrolling / Enable horizontal
>   scrolling
>
> [image]

To edit the are used for scrolling, edit this at:

> Virtual Scrolling > Scrolling Region
>
> [image]

If these options, aren't available, then try downloading the latest touchpad drivers (manufacturer specific) from the [Toshiba website](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/home.jsp?nav=Download), otherwise try directly from the [Synaptics site](http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers).

You could also explore the driver settings, to see if you can enable two-finger scrolling. I haven't seen this on my HP-based synaptics drivers though (seems I'm using driver version 6.xx, latest is 10.1.8).

Disclaimer on Synaptics website:

> The Synaptics device driver is
>   customized to meet the specific
>   requirements of your device
>   manufacturer. To ensure that you get
>   the appropriate device driver for your
>   system, download your Synaptics device
>   driver from your system manufacturer's
>   support website